# Remove text between two strings Applescript

Tags: string, applescript

I have successfully grabbed the text I want to delete but then when I try and delete the chunk of text I have specified it throws an error

```
set startText to "<target object=\"3097595957\" channel=\"./2/100\" name=\"\"/>"
set endText to "<target object=\"3097805072\" channel=\"./2/100\" name=\"\"/>"

set theFile to POSIX path of newNameFull
set theContent to read theFile as «class utf8»

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startText
set bigChunk to text items of theContent
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endText

        repeat with subText in bigChunk

            if subText contains endText then

                display dialog subText

                delete subText

            end if

        end repeat
```

When I display the subtext it is the correct text that I want to be removed.  But then when i try to delete it i get this error:

```
Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class. (-10010)
```

I have tried researching this error and I am thoroughly confused.  If anyone has any advice or can help then that would be greatly appreciate.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `delete` command needs a target. You want to delete the `subText` from *something*. In a `Finder` tell block the target is the `Finder` itself and this causes the error.

Comment: I guessI am really confused by this.  I didnt post my entire code but I already have it inside of 'tell application "Finder"' . Is there an Applescript command to delete this chunk of text?

Comment: Again, delete from **what**? You need an object to delete something from.

Comment: So I have my variable theFile which is the path to my file I am trying to delete the text from and then I also have theContent which reads the entire file.  What is the syntax then?  "delete subText from theFile"?  What is the correct syntax then for referencing the object I am trying to delete from?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. `bigChunk` is a list of text items. Do you want to delete the particular text item from the list if it contains the text in `endText`?

Comment: I want to delete all the text between the startText and the endText.  Thats the end goal.

Comment: I have even tried using shell script do shell script ("sed '/" & startText & "/,/" & endText & "/{//!d}' " & theFile & "") . It keeps throwing me an error: "sed: 1: "/<target object="309759 ...": invalid command code 2"

Comment: There are two other questions: Delete the text including `startText` and `endText`? And are there multiple occurrences of `startText` and `endText` in the text?

Comment: No there are no other occurrences and i don't want to delete the startText and endText.  I only want to delete the text in between them.

Comment: I wrote an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

- Get the text **before** `startText` (text1)
- Get the text **after** `endText` (text2)
- Concatenate `text1 & startText & endText & text2`

---

```
set startText to "<target object=\"3097595957\" channel=\"./2/100\" name=\"\"/>"
set endText to "<target object=\"3097805072\" channel=\"./2/100\" name=\"\"/>"

set theFile to POSIX path of newNameFull
set theContent to read theFile as «class utf8»

set ASTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startText
set text1 to text item 1 of theContent
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endText
set text2 to text item 2 of theContent
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
set trimmedText to text1 & startText & endText & text2
```

The result is in the variable `trimmedText`. You might save the text back to disk.

Comment: Ah i see.  This makes way more sense than what I was trying to do.  I see where you're going with this now.  I do have one issue where my Applescript throws an error: "Can’t get text item 2 of " and then my entire file's contents.  This doesn't make sense if text item 1 was able to get the contents...why cant the second text item ?

Comment: If this error occurs then `theContent` does not contain `endText`.

Comment: Yep you are right.  The text was not uniform for all the files I was trying to edit.  Thank you so much for your help.